# useNetInfo not working when connection is reestablished

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

I'm using `react-native-netinfo` to keep track of my device's internet connection. It was working fine for the most part until the point where the internet is disconnected and comes back on. At this point `NetInfo` does not respond with the correct internet state.

While going over the repo on github it looks like this is a known issue without a fix yet. In one of the threads, there was a mention of using the hook `useNetInfo` instead cos apparently that still worked fine.

So I tried that out as mentioned here https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/issues/400#issuecomment-953177841 but even this isn't returning the correct state when the connection is established again.

I'm not sure what to do now. I don't know if there is more to this hook or if it needs to be implemented differently.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to make it work was to add an event listener in **componentDidMount()** and remove the listener in **componentWillUnMount()**.

```
componentDidMount(){
 NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
                this.handleConnectivityChange(isConnected === undefined ? true : isConnected);
            });
            NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
                'connectionChange',
                this.handleConnectivityChange
            );}
```

My handleConnectivityChange() function stores the isConnected boolean in redux to be used wherever I want.

```
componentWillUnMount() {
NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
            'connectionChange',
            this.handleConnectivityChange
        );
}
```

Comment: Can you add the source of this example. I found this example in older docs from when NetInfo was part of react-native

Comment: Yup, the NetInfo I am using is from @react-native-community/netinfo.